# How to distinguish between two multiple selection lists with same name

Tags: php, html, forms, post

For a system I'm building I need to see which options came in (with POST request) from the first list and which options came in from the second list.

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="cars[]" multiple>
        <option selected>test</option>
        <option selected>test2</option>
        <option>test3</option>
        <option>test4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="cars[]" multiple>
        <option>hai</option>
        <option>hai2</option>
        <option selected>hai3</option>
        <option selected>hai4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now they're coming in like this:

```
Array
(
    [cars] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test2
            [2] => hai3
            [3] => hai4
        )
)
```

Actually I want to retrieve the 'testX' options apart from the 'haiX' options. Now I can't see which came from the first list and which from the second. Off course I know I could also make the name of the second list different than the name of the first list, but it's for good reason that I want to do it like this.

Comment: Are you not able to use a different unique name for the 2nd field? e.g. `cars[]` and `type[]` ?

Comment: Like I said, I've good reason for wanting it to have te same name.. 
Or there must be some other way to place an unspecified number of multiple selection lists on a page and fetching them easily with PHP.

Comment: Are you able to use multiple forms? e.g. `form id=1 name=1 select=name[] ... form id=2 name=2 select=name[]`

Comment: Not sure what reason you have for having duplicate names under the same form, that hinders what you are trying to accomplish without adding hidden values in select select value and do more parsing on the post e.g. `option value=frm1|value1 ... option value=frm2|value1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the categories by creating a multidimensional array in the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="cars[0][]" multiple>
        <option selected>test</option>
        <option selected>test2</option>
        <option>test3</option>
        <option>test4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="cars[1][]" multiple>
        <option>hai</option>
        <option>hai2</option>
        <option selected>hai3</option>
        <option selected>hai4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then reading it like this: $_POST['cars'][0] for the first set and $_POST['cars'][1] for the second

Comment: Haha.. what the heck. This works! I tried the cars[0] and cars[1] but obviously those extra [] are needed.

And about those unique names ^^: in this case that not a problem because I can let PHP walk trough $_POST['cars'] and ignore the array keys.

Comment: In case you're confused about how this works at all, you can also set set the arrays like this: <select name="cars['category_name_1'][]" multiple>. And access like this: $_POST['cars']['category_name_1']. My understanding of it is that the extra brackets at the end of the name is PHP's way of signifying that you're pushing an element onto the end of the array. So I tried this and it worked. Didn't know it was possible myself.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by using a hidden field(input) for each select list.you might name them as you want  and thats how to know.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite an effective solution. Will mark this as answer until something better shows up! If you give those hidden fields also an array name (hiddenName[]) you can get all names of lists trough that one hiddenName POST variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve them like this:

`$_POST['cars'][0]` refers to the "test" set

`$_POST['cars'][1]` refers to the "hai" set

Comment: I don't believe @Ttony21 is correct its a single array cars with x items not a multidimensional array

Comment: Oh I think I understand the problem here, due to the 'multiple' attribute.

Comment: @dirt no, I checked my code and it does return values, but the problem is that she's allowing multiple selections, so the data isn't divided in the array

Comment: Right, $_POST[0-3] with no way of telling which select it came from (without assuming orders) and OP wants to know which select it came from.

Comment: Added a new answer that I've tested. Works properly, but I'm not sure if it fits the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I made this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['cars']))
    {
      $test = array();
      $hai = array();

      $lista = $_POST['cars'];
      foreach ($lista as $key ) {
          if (substr($key,0,1)=="t")
          {
            $test[] = $key;
          }
          else
          {
            $hai[] = $key;
          }
      }
    }
    var_dump($test);
    var_dump($hai);
    ?>


    <form method="post">
        <select name="cars[]" multiple>
            <option selected>test</option>
            <option selected>test2</option>
            <option>test3</option>
            <option>test4</option>
        </select>
        <select name="cars[]" multiple>
            <option>hai</option>
            <option>hai2</option>
            <option selected>hai3</option>
            <option selected>hai4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Tested on localhost.

Saludos :)

Comment: No, this only works if option names have a different start in each list, but that's not the case (only in my demo).

Comment: Nice answer @Ttony21 ....it's the first time i saw something like that....i tested too and works like a charm xD