# Multiple multiselect option - How to get in PHP

Tags: php

```html
<div><select name="languages_known[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">UK</option>
<option value="2">EN</option>
<option value="3">HI</option>
<option value="4">AN</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
<select name="languages_known[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">UK</option>
<option value="2">EN</option>
<option value="3">HI</option>
<option value="4">AN</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Note: Both the multi select box names are the same i.e. languages_known[]. 
How can get the values if user selected "1 & 2 from 1st box" and "1, 3 & 4 from 2nd box" at the same time, in PHP? I have to save the values in two different rows in MySQL. Like:

in row #1, the column name "input_val" will contain 1,2 and 
in row #2, the column name "input_val" will contain 1,3,4.

If there is another multi select box with the same name, mysql row #3 will be created as follows:
in row #3, the column name "input_val" will contain 2,4 etc.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Apparently, you don't need to do anything special: the browser doesn't care about duplicate control names and PHP merges both controls into the same array because it doesn't know they come from different places. What's your exact problem?

Comment: @tereško this link has nothing to do with the question being asked

Comment: Why do you need to use the same name, when you don't want to have it in the same name?

Comment: Are you asking how to save these given values in to an SQL database?

Comment: @Martin - Yes. My concern is to get those values and later save them to mysql row by row. I have modified my question above.

Answer (score 2):

The output will be:

```
$_POST['languages_known'][0] = 2;
$_POST['languages_known'][1] = 1;
$_POST['languages_known'][2] = 3;
$_POST['languages_known'][3] = 4;
```

because using the `multiple="multiple"` attribute (along with the `[]` name part) will pass all the values to PHP as array elements (thus none will be overwritten when posted).

You can then `array_walk` or `foreach` through this `$_POST['languages_known']` array on the receiving page.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8931368/3536236).

---

## Update

> I have to save the values in two different rows in MySQL.

If you have to save these two nuggets of information to two different rows, simply restructure your two form names such as then giving each seperate array rows:

```
<div><select name="languages_known[][]" multiple="multiple">
 ....
</div>

<div><select name="languages_known[][]" multiple="multiple">
 ....
</div>
```

This will then give you:

```
$_POST['languages_known'][0][0] = 2;
$_POST['languages_known'][0][1] = 1;
$_POST['languages_known'][1][2] = 3;
$_POST['languages_known'][1][3] = 4;
```

---

Overall, I'm afraid as the question is not 100% clear, I'm using some guesswork to answer you, so you should [heavily edit and improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What sort of MySQL columns, what data types; details, details, ***details***!

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have modified my question for better understanding.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara I'm afraid if the question is obscure (as it currently seems to be) you will need to [heavily edit and improve your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What sort of MySQL columns, what data types, details, details, ***details***!

Comment: Edited. Please check and answer.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623357/how-to-distinguish-between-two-multiple-selection-lists-with-same-name.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara pleased to hear it, although that Question has the same answer as I gave here (multiple arrays)!! `:-D`

Comment: I saw your answer. The problem was, I was not able to differentiate the values, i.e. For Box 1, I selected values 1, 2; For Box 2, I selected another set of values etc. But needless to say, from your answer and comments, I was able to understand the basic problem. My vote is for you Martin.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara hah, thanks. Yeah I suppose you could manually set the outer array `name="languages[1][]"` but that's somewhat inflexible if it's a dynamically generated list. Anyhow, I'm glad you found a solution `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form method="post">
    <select name="cars[0][]" multiple>
        <option selected>test</option>
        <option selected>test2</option>
        <option>test3</option>
        <option>test4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="cars[1][]" multiple>
        <option>hai</option>
        <option>hai2</option>
        <option selected>hai3</option>
        <option selected>hai4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And then reading it like this: $_POST['cars'][0] for the first set and $_POST['cars'][1] for the second. Based on this, I can store the values on different MySQL rows.

Courtesy: [How to distinguish between two multiple selection lists with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623357/how-to-distinguish-between-two-multiple-selection-lists-with-same-name)